# Select Item in Kendo Listview with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, listview, kendo-ui

I have a kendo listview:

```
<div kendo-list-view k-data-source="demo" k-selectable="'single'" k-change="'showDetails(dataItem)'"  k-data-reload="'true'" class="clearfix">
```

And bind the data in my angular controller:

```
$scope.demo = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [/* some objects */],
    pageSize: 6
});
```

Now I want to select the first item on the first page in the listview. But how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First item will be selected:

```
var item = $(".demoItem:first").attr("data-uid");
var listView = $("div[kendo-list-view]").data("kendoListView");
listView.select(listView.element.find("[data-uid='" + item + "']"));
```

Comment: what is `demoItem` here ? any class used in UI ?

Comment: "with AngularJS"  - this answer only uses jquery